# How to stop elements moving when rezising the screen?

Tags: html, css, web

im fairly new to Html,css and im currently making a very amateurish website,  the problem i came across is whenever i try to rezise the window from fullscreen to very small everything starts to move even my Navigation bar becomes Vertical at some point, it feels some parts arent "locked" in place lets say it like that ill give you a link to my website so you can see for yourself also my Html and css codes are below,any idea how to fix this? i already tried searching and adding the following code but without any succes..
http://dwaight.magix.net/public/#
thanks in advance..

**HTML CODE**

```
<body> 
<div class="container"> 
<div class="header">
    <h1 style="margin-top:0;">KYOTO INDUNSTIRES</h1></div>
<ul div class="nav">
    <ul style="list-style: none; ">
  <li><a href="#">Kyoto</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>

<div class="content">Hier komt de inhoud van de pagina. </div> 
<div class="footer">Hier plaats je de footer. </div> 
</div> 
</body>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.header h1  {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "GatsbyFLF";
    font-size: 150px;

}
.nav {
    font-size: 250%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
.nav li {
    float: left; }
.nav li a {
    font-family: "GatsbyFLF";
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }

.nav li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happened here is the content is simply flowing.

It's a good thing that your elements re-position themselves.  This allows your content to be visible no matter what the resolution is.  The trick is to get your content to re-position in a way that is controlled.

A quick and dirty method is to simply set a minimum width on the outer container of your site.  This can be done with CSS:

```
min-width: 60em;
```

Really though, if you do this a user is going to have to scroll side to side to see your content.  It's often best to let the flow work itself out.  If you want additional control, you can look into [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) which allow you to set different CSS properties for different resolutions and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

in your container div you should put a min width. That way you're website will descrease until it hits the minimum width limit.

```
.container{
    min-width:1000px;
}
```

hope it helps!

plus an extra: font-sizes you should probably consider avoiding percentages, and use "em" when necessary (1em = 14px)

Comment: `1em` is `1em`, not `14px`.  It's a relative size.  You can never say what that size is, unless you defined it.

Comment: true, but for relation in size with pixels, it's approximately 14px

Comment: No, it isn't!  It has nothing to do with pixels.  And if you're referring to the default sizes, they depend entirely on the browser and device.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH GUYS!

-Dwight

Answer (score 0):

you can add a width to the container

```
.container{width: 1200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `<nav>` a minimum width:

```
nav{
min-width:1200px;
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/08Lc2cee/)
Your layout is breaking because the elements only stay horizontal if the window is large enough, but as it grows smaller, they flow down as they are supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your developer tools and find the maximum width of the screen before things start going wrong (I think this is about 1100 pixels for your page). Then in your CSS code add:

```
html {
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

This will mean that if the window width is less that 400 pixels (change this to the actual value worked out above), then the page will just stay at 400 pixels and use horizontal scroll bars.

Whilst this will work, it generally isn't considered best practice. Look at http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ for a better solution.